# How to open another JFrame with selected RadioButton according to data in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jradiobutton

I am trying to send data to `JFrame` named `UpdateCar` using a button. Data should say which radio button should be selected.

```
btnUpdateCar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
            UpdateCar updatePage = new UpdateCar();
            updatePage.setVisible(true);
            
            int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();

            updatePage.buttonGroup.setSelected(getSelectedButton(model,selectedRow).getModel(),true);   
// when I use above line it doesn't work. But instead if I use the thing it will return, it works for that value.
        }
    });
```

I wrote a method like this for this purpose:

```
public JRadioButton getSelectedButton(DefaultTableModel model, int selectedRow) {
    
    String selectedButton = (String) model.getValueAt(selectedRow,3);
    UpdateCar updatePage = new UpdateCar();
    
    if(selectedButton.equals("Automatic")) {
        
        return updatePage.rdbtnAutomatic;
        
    }else {
        return updatePage.rdbtnManuel;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"How to open another JFrame with selected RadioButton according to data in JTable?"* This goes wrong right at *"another JFrame"*. Each app. should have only one. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently both method and btnUpdateCar's action perfrom method should have same reference for target JFrame. I was using two different calls for that JFrame. Now I have global variable for that Jframe and problem solved.